# Can the Diablo 3 game client be copied from one PC to another?

Tags: diablo-iii

We have downloaded the Diablo 3 game client on one PC at our house. With the other two recent Blizzard games WoW and Starcraft 2 you could just copy the game folder from one PC to another over the LAN and fire it up. Is this also possible with the Diablo 3 game client?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The client is not account specific.

Comment: What about silly things like registry entries and whatnot?  How are those replicated on machine #2?

Comment: Well it is not the same as installing the game from scratch (no startmenu entries etc.) Usually if no registry entry is found it is replaced with a default until the user sets his preferences. I do not work at Blizzard, so I am not sure :)

Comment: Copied from PC 1 to PC 2, create shortcut to D3.exe on desktop, run... working like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

I have confirmed this.  Just like *World of Warcraft*, you **can move/copy/cut the entire directory (~15GB) to anywhere you would like**.  I tested this by moving it between hard drives on my local machine.

The **only** problem would be the shortcuts on the desktop not pointing to the correct location, but you can always use the launcher found in the Diablo 3 container.

Once you have D3 installed on one computer, instead of downloading it again, use an external Hard drive to copy it from computer-to-computer!

Answer (score 4):

While you can copy your Diablo 3 folder to an external hard disk, it is worth noting that Diablo 3 stores additional data in the following locations;

```
C:\ProgramData\Battle.net
C:\ProgramData\Blizzard Entertainment
```

The 'ProgramData' folder requires administrative privileges in order to write files to this location, so simply 'just' copying your Diablo 3 folder won't work but the Diablo 3 launcher should rebuild these folders and all related files if you have access to these locations.

These folders contain the Battle.Net Agent in addition to Diablo 3 Launcher updates and are required for the Launcher to update.

There is the 'current' copy of the launcher in the Diablo 3 installation folder, so provided you have write access to the above locations on the new computer running this will re-create all of the required folders and re-download all of the required files for the Battle.net agent.

Comment: but there is a launcher in the main Diablo III folder.