# Can I run Diablo 3 on 2 different battle.net accounts with 1 disc?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to buy multiple games to be able to play Diablo 3 with my wife?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66435/do-i-need-to-buy-multiple-games-to-be-able-to-play-diablo-3-with-my-wife)

My brother has the physical disc copy of Diablo 3. I want to play it also, but not on his Battle.net account. My question is, can I use the same disc he used to install it on his computer to install it on mine, but use a different battle.net account?

Comment: Does the other account have Diablo 3 licensed?

Answer (score 2):

Diablo 3 doesn't use the disc to actually launch the game, just to perform the install.  Assuming the second account also has Diablo 3 on it, you'll be fine to use his disc.

Answer (score 2):

If the second account has Diablo III registered, it will work.  However, you cannot log in to Diablo III with an account that does not have it registered.

However, you may purchase the game online, and then use the disc to install it.