# Battle.net accounts and Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to buy multiple games to be able to play Diablo 3 with my wife?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66435/do-i-need-to-buy-multiple-games-to-be-able-to-play-diablo-3-with-my-wife)

My boyfriend has Diablo 3 on his computer but I don't want to use his Battle.net account.

If I register my own battle account can I play on his computer without having to purchase another copy of Diablo 3?

Comment: Hi Jacey, and welcome to Arqade!  Have a look at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66435/), because it should answer what you're asking.  I also flagged your question as a duplicate of that, so this question might get closed in the near future.  Just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Diablo 3 is a Battle.net account bound game, this means that while you could create your own account (which is free), you would also need to purchase your own copy of Diablo 3 on that account in order to play with your own account.

Comment: that really sucks!!

Comment: Is it because too many people were creating accounts and setting characters to auto to make more gold or what....

Comment: No it's because Blizzard want you to buy their game, the way it works is only one person can be logged into Diablo 3 per Battle.net account, logging in a second time logs you out - meaning one copy of the game can only be in use once at a time per region, allowing you to log in multiple times using separate accounts would mean less people buy the game.

Comment: But if it's on the same computer-

Comment: Blizzard don't care about that, the only solution would be to use the same account if only one of you is going to be playing at once - if you want separate accounts, you will need to buy the game twice.

Comment: Oh well- guess I will just play on his account.